# backbone - why wont this render to my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Why won't this render to my html page using backbone.js

here are my  scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/backbone.min.js"></script>

<script>
    (function ($) {

        var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('body'), // el attaches to existing element
            events: {
                'click button#add': 'addItem'
            },
            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

                this.counter = 0; // total number of items added thus far
                this.render();
            },
            render: function () {
                $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>Add list item</button>");
                $(this.el).append("<ul></ul>");
            },
            addItem: function () {
                this.counter++;
                $('ul', this.el).append("<li>hello world" + this.counter + "</li>");
            }
        });

        var listView = new ListView();

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/Sunderscore.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/underscore.js"></script>
```

If that doesn't work, check if javascript libraries are in the same directory with this HTML.

Comment: thanks but its not that - thats an error when I coppied and pasted it in

Comment: Then check if your javascript libraries are on the right path. Actually it works when I set the right library path.

Comment: @Hello-World check http://jsfiddle.net/hzheng/mJAQj/ and see if it works as you expect. The only change I made is getting javascript's src from CDN.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have a typo in

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/Sunderscore.js"></script>
```

Didn't you mean

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/underscore.js"></script>
```

? (underscore.js in stead of Sunderscore.js)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your underscore declaration script is right in the project you are testing, I'd say you got the el declarations wrong:

```
el: 'body',
```

then you access it (assuming you use jQuery using $el and not el.

Comment: Don't think it's that, read bb source    setElement: function(element, delegate) {
      if (this.$el) this.undelegateEvents();
      this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
      this.el = this.$el[0];
      if (delegate !== false) this.delegateEvents();
      return this;
    },